# Laravel 5.1 resource route does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

```
// routes.php
Route::resource('/image', 'ImageController');
Route::get('/create', 'ImageController@create');
Route::post('/store', 'ImageController@store');

// create.blade.php
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/store', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}
    .......
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here if i don't write these two lines (Route::get('/create', 'ImageController@create'); Route::post('/store', 'ImageController@store');)
The resource routing of create and store does not work and show some errors.
Why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors does it show?

Comment: Try to remove that '/' :- `Route::resource('image', 'ImageController');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating resource route you don't have to create individual routes. Because all RESTfull default routes will be created for you automatically.

You just need following route

```
Route::resource('image', 'ImageController');
```

then change `form` as below

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('image.store'))) !!}
    .......
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[Read More](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)